# Unit testing security model ClickOnce

Tags: .net, security, unit-testing, clickonce

I am fiddling around trying to install an application via ClickOnce - with certain minimum permissions. I'd like to unit test to assert that my application does not use any additional functionality disallowed by the wanted security policy.

Can I in my unit test specify that I want to use the specified manifest to regulate permissions, make calls to my library and then assert that no security exceptions are thrown?

If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to unit test (test in isolation) you have to

- test permissionLogic and you have to
- test that your contrologic (i.e. MVVM) uses the permission logic.

**Test SecurityManager for permissionLogic**

you can **extract the permissionLogic to a class of its own** with methods

```
public class SecurityManager
{
 bool IsAllowedToPrint(User user);
 bool IsAllowedToAdminister(User user);
}
```

then you write unit tests

```
 User user = CreateAdimistrator();
 Assert.AreEqual(true, securityManager.IsAllowedToAdminister(user));
```

**Contrologic (i.e. MVVM) uses permission logic**

create a mock-SecurityManager that always allow/disallow functionality.
and write unit tests for the controller if it reacts as expected.

```
var allowEverythingMock = CreateSecurityManagerMockThatAllowsEverything();
var mvvm = CreateMvvm(allowEverythingMock );
Assert.IsNotNull(mvvm.GetAdminGui());
```

I am not shure if there is an easy way to create an integration-test where Click-Once-App actually uses the real SecurityManager and the result gets verified.

**Update after getting more infos on what the goal is**

write unit tests for the controller if it reacts as expected.

```
var controller = CreateCreate(Permission.Low);

try
{
   // File io is not allowed with low permissions
   controller.SaveTextAsFile("HellowWorld", @"c:\temp\UnittestResult.txt");
   Assert.Fail("The Controller should have forbidden this");
} catch(PermissionException pex) {
   // everything is ok. This specific exception was expected.
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you... My app don't have the concept of users, the fact is simply that it will be run in a low-permissive context and thus cannot write/read files at random etc. I want to make sure via unit-tests that I can run my program with the low permissions described in the application manifest...

Comment: I have updated my example. "I want to make sure via unit-tests that I can run my program with the low permissions described in the application manifest". Since you are refeferencing filesystem/manifest you are looking for an integration-test not for a unittest. Sorry i hve no experience in writing manifest-based-Click-Once-Integrationtests

Comment: have you seen [testing-clickonce-applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730090/testing-clickonce-applications?)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but close enough that I'll accept the answer! Hoped for an answer that told me how to run my tests in the actual low-permission environment. That would have let me run my code and if no exception is thrown then all is good. Would have been problematic though.