# Unit Test(mvc) -problem with Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, security-roles, user-roles

I have mvc application and I'm working with poco objects and writing unit test. Problem is that all my test fail when they reach this line of code Roles.IsUserInRole("someUser", "role"). Should I implement new interface or repository for Roles or...?
Thx

Comment: There isn't enough info here to answer your question.  Please consider revising/adding code/adding details to your question.

Comment: Why do they fail? Can you post details of the exception and which framework you are using? Most frameworks use types of exceptions to fail, so it may be a fail or an exception caused by the isolation for the test.

Comment: I have implemented Role testing in the controller similar to [unit-testing-security-model-clickonce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585174/unit-testing-security-model-clickonce/4585686#4585686)

Comment: This is error message : System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to mock the Roles.IsUserInRole functionality in my coded unit tests. My solution was to create a new class called RoleProvider and an interface with method IsUserInRole which then called the System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole:

```
public class RoleProvider: IRoleProvider
{
    public bool IsUserInRole(IPrincipal userPrincipal)
    {
        return System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(userPrincipal.Identity.Name, "User");
    }
}
```

Then in my code I call the RoleProvider IsUserInRole method. As you have an interface you can then mock the IRoleProvider in your tests, example shown here is using Rhino Mocks:

```
var roleProvider = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRoleProvider>();
roleProvider.Expect(rp => rp.IsUserInRole(userPrincipal)).Return(true);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is very excellent for testability. Kinda annoying that my controllers now need an instance of RoleProvider, though. May end up creating a base controller class that has this built in (along with some other common properties/fields). Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a custom method to check roles that will behave differently in tests, but I prefer to have the tests set up a context that will work with the standard methods.

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/01/asp-net-mvc-tip-12-faking-the-controller-context.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create a light wrapper with a Predicate/Func.

```
public static Predicate<string> IsUserInRole = role => Roles.IsUserInRole(role);
```

Then use IsUserInRole() instead of Roles.IsUserInRole().  At run time you get the same behavior.  But at test time you can override the function so that it doesn't access the RoleProvider

```
MyClass.IsUserInRole = role => true;
```

If you prefer to not have a public static you could inject the Predicate via your constructor and store it as a private readonly.

```
class MyClass
{    
    private readonly Predicate<string> IsUserInRole;
    MyClass(Predicate<string> roleChecker) { this.IsUserInRole = roleChecker }
    MyClass() : this(role => Roles.IsUserInRole(role)) { }
}
```

If you use Moq you can return a mock and then control the return value and/or check the method was called.  And check what parameter value was sent to the Predicate.

```
Mock<Predicate<string>> mockRoleChecker = new Mock<Predicate<string>>();
var cut = new MyClass(mockRoleChecker.Object);
var expectedRole = "Admin";
mockRoleChecker.SetReturnsDefault<bool>(true);  // if not specified will return false which is default(bool)

cut.MyMethod();

mockRoleChecker.Verify(x => x(expectedRole), Times.Once());
```